# How to get start, finish time and status kubernetes jobs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I try to use

```
kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=TIMESTAMP:.metadata.creationTimestamp,NAME:.metadata.name
```

but can't find custom columns for 'ending at' and 'status'.

Where can I find a columns list for kubectl get and describe job?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `status` section of the job to get the required details.

The completion time is present at `.status.completionTime` and the status at `.status.conditions[].type`.

```
kubectl get jobs dummy-xxxx-xxxx -o custom-columns=TIMESTAMP:.metadata.creationTimestamp,NAME:.metadata.name,COMPLETIONTIME:.status.completionTime,status:.status.conditions[].type

TIMESTAMP              NAME                  COMPLETIONTIME         status
2021-02-08T14:40:03Z   dummy-xxxx-xxxx   2021-02-08T14:40:50Z     Complete

kubectl get jobs dummy-yyyy-yyyy -o custom-columns=TIMESTAMP:.metadata.creationTimestamp,NAME:.metadata.name,COMPLETIONTIME:.status.completionTime,status:.status.conditions[].type

TIMESTAMP              NAME               COMPLETIONTIME      status
2021-02-08T12:00:08Z   dummy-yyyy-yyyy       <none>           Failed
```

Note that the completion time is not set for the `Failed` jobs and there was already a [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68712)  that mentions this problem.

> When a Job completes (finished successfully), its
> .status.completionTime will be set, and Job conditions will have one
> with type==Complete.
>
> When a Job fails, Job conditions will have one with type==Failed.